# How to disable django recapture for testing or anything?

Tags: python, django, recaptcha

How to disable django recapture for testing?.I'm using django-recaptcha==1.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the solution for disable django-recaptcha.Its simple.We need to set environment varible RECAPTCHA_TESTING

eg:

```
import os
os.environ['RECAPTCHA_TESTING'] = 'True'
```

put this two lines to your'e settings.py file.It's work fine for me.

I'm using django-recaptcha==1.0.2 i hope i's work fine with other versions.

related question https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha/issues/82

Comment: Not work for me.